# How to create Geopandas buffers for locations around the World

Tags: coordinates, geopandas, map-projections, epsg

I have a location dataset (points long & lat) for events that happened around the World. I want to create 5km rings around these locations using `Geopandas.buffer` function. As explained [in a previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383014/how-to-use-geopandas-buffer-function-to-get-buffer-zones-in-kilometers), I first transform to meters and then compute the buffers.

I realized that [EPSG:32634](https://epsg.io/32634) is not appropriate for every country. Do I have to manually pick the "best" projection for each point or is there a way to code this?

Comment: You might have more luck with this question on [gis.se]

Comment: My hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400300/plot-a-circle-on-a-cartopy-mercator-projection  it works on any projection.

Comment: Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709468/wrong-points-buffer-using-geopandas/74783942#74783942